# verilog always block within a initial block not proper syntax?

Tags: debugging, verilog

I keep getting weird syntax errors,  I was wondering if anyone knows why I am getting these errors.     I read that you can't have an always block within a initial block,  but when I try to move the always block outside the initial block I still get an error.

[image]

[image]

Update:   Problem solved.   Although, I simply moved the always block outside of the initial block, and I stopped receiving the syntax errors.    Answer provided by [Why are always blocks not allowed in...](http://asicwithankit.blogspot.ca/2010/01/why-are-always-block-is-not-allowed-in.html) [image]

Answer (score 4):

Two syntax rules:

- Repeat blocks must be within initial blocks
- Always blocks must be outside initial blocks.